# What does the absolute valued expression actually mean according to this?

Tags: absolute-value

Does this mean that for an absolute value of $x$, we can either get two values of $x$ which must be greater than or equal to $0$ or two values where if one is negative then the other must be positive and they both must be less than $0$? Thanks a lot!

> For the absolute valued expression $|x|$, we have:
>
> $\bbox[5px,#e2f9fe]{|x|=\begin{cases}x,&x\ge0\\-x,&x<0\end{cases}}$

Answer (score 0):

It says that if x is negative, the result is $-x$, which is $x$, and if it is positive, is $x$.

Comment: But how can the result be -x??

Comment: @monishkumar this is because |-2|=-(-2)=2